# Вывод на экран значения переменной типа double в неэкспоненциальной форме

Tags: c++, c

Нужно вывести на экран переменную типа `double` - в обычной форме записи (не экспоненциальной), с точностью настолько, насколько хватит размерности в типе `double`.
Я сначала пробовал:

```
cout<<fixed<<setprecision(Poridok)<<Answer;

// Answer - переменная типа double которую вывести

 // Poridok –  кол-во знаков, которое будет выведено.
```

Но проблема в том, что как я понял, в компьютере `double` хранится в экспоненциальной форме и может иметь  масштабы в диапазоне от 10 в -308 степени до  10 в 308 степени. Соответственно я не знаю, как вычислить `Poridok`, так, что бы число при выводе на печать некогда не обрезалась, и в тоже время, не отображать для каждого числа 10 в 308 степени знаков, а отображать столько знаков, сколько действительно есть в числе. Помогите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Для типа double мантиса 52 бита то есть не более 16 символов посмотри вопрос (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/84005/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-double-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B5?rq=1)

Comment: `printf("%.16g", ...)` (см. man fprintf)  (эээ..., кончайте вытаскивать старье!)

Answer (score 2):

### С++ (cout):

```
cout.precision(5);
cout << fixed << result << endl;
```

### C(printf):

```
printf ("%.5f\n", result);
```