# Печать значения типа double в обычной десятичной форме

Tags: c, visual-studio, c++

Нужно вывести на экран значение переменной типа `double`. При этом нужно, чтобы при любых значениях этой переменной на экран выводилось бы значение не в экспоненциальной форме, а в обычной десятичной, 64.34232 и т.д., безо всяких "e". При этом точность должна быть, насколько хватит размерности `double`. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Важно понимать, что точность десятичной формы двоичного `double` нельзя просто и точно пересчитать из двоичной точности, которая заключена в 11 битах степени и 52 битах мантиссы.

Answer (score 4):

```
std::cout.setf(std::ios::fixed);    // установка флага
std::cout << 1112123124241244.5534344 << std::endl;
std::cout.unsetf(std::ios::fixed);  // сброс флага
```

либо

```
std::cout << std::ios::fixed << 55555555.3333333 << std::endl;
```

Comment: А во втором варианте что получается на выходе? (hint: манипулятор --std::fixed, кажется)

Answer (score 0):

Так этот вопрос уже обсасывался, вроде бы?

```
stringstream ss;
ss << fixed << 1.2;
string s = ss.str();
while(s[s.length()-1] == '0') s.erase(s.length()-1);
cout << s << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Сорок знаков после запятой, полагаю, хватит с избытком:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("i = %.40f\n", (double)0.00000000000001);
    return 0;
}
```

Однако следует понимать, что абсолютно точно число double можно вывести только в "сыром" виде, как оно хранится в компьютере. Для этого используется спецификатор a вместо f.